# Redirect to security-trimmed menu node

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I've implemented SiteMap Security Trimming as described in this tutorial: [ASP.NET Menu and SiteMap Security Trimming](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx)

The menu works as expected. I would like to take it one step further and redirect the user to the first node in the resulting trimmed menu. The menu will be different for every user based on their roles, so the redirect URL would need to be derived from the either the menu itself, or from the sitemap file.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out one option, at least: I created an event handler for MenuItemDataBound, and redirected based on the Url of the first item bound to the menu, like so:

On the aspx, set the Menu's `OnMenuItemDataBound="Menu1_MenuItemDataBound"`

Then created the following method in the code-behind:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    string Url = ((SiteMapNode)e.Item.DataItem).Url;
    Response.Redirect(Url);
}
```

Seems to work as expected. If you have a better solution, let me know.